# How to get Location if device screen is off?

Tags: android, location, android-location, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I am working on app that has to get location after some fixed interval. It is working fine. But when device' screen is off, it is not getting location.
For this I am trying WakeLock.
When I use PowerManager.LOCATION_MODE_NO_CHANGE, it is crashing the app without any logs.
Please help me to use this (PowerManager.LOCATION_MODE_NO_CHANGE).
I am using it in onCreate of MainActivity.

```
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.LOCATION_MODE_NO_CHANGE, "My Tag");
        mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to Power Saver mode.
If power saver mode is on then device will not get location on screen off. So, to get location (on screen off), we have to turn off the screen saver mode.

Comment: How to turn off screen saver mode, Any hints?